# PowerShell: Compare files in two different folder

Tags: powershell, copy, compare

I have a source folder and a destination folder. If a file in the source folder is newer than the file in the destination folder, it must be replaced.
I have tried it myself, but it does not work as it should. The code is probably solved too complicated for professionals.

```
$SourceAlarmgroups = $rootPath + "\..\..\..\..\..\..\Logical\VCShared\AlarmGroups"
$DestinationAlarmgroups = "$rootPath\Alarmgroups"

$lastModifiedDateSource = (Get-Item $SourceAlarmgroups).LastWriteTime
$lastModifiedDateDestination = (Get-Item $DestinationAlarmgroups).LastWriteTime

$FolderSource = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SourceAlarmgroups
$FolderDestination = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $DestinationAlarmgroups

$FolderCheck = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FolderSource -DifferenceObject $FolderDestination

forEach($file in $FolderCheck){
    if ($file.sideindicator -eq "<="){
        $SetWriteCmd = 1
    }
}
if ($lastModifiedDateSource -gt $lastModifiedDateDestination -or $SetWriteCmd -eq 1 ){
    Write-Host " Collect alarm files..." 
    Get-ChildItem $SourceAlarmgroups -Include *.algrp | Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationAlarmGroups -Force -PassThru
    &$Script2RunAlarmexport
}else{ 
    Write-Host "Alarms: Already up to date"   
}
```

Two problems arise:

1. referencing to an empty folder does not work, i.e. if the destination folder is empty there is an error.
2. the files are not copied from source to destination

Can someone help me.
TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 1.:

You need to check if your folder is empty:

```
$DestinationFolder= Get-ChildItem "DestinationFolder" | Measure-Object


if (-not($DestinationFolder.count -eq 0)) 
{
    "execute your code"
    break;
}
```

You could also use Test-Path if you know for which path or at least file ending you are looking for (example what I used)

```
if ( Test-Path  "C:\Test") 
{
    Write-host "C:\Test already exists, either delete the directory or change to another directory in the code"
    break;
}
```

for 2.:

Even in the pipe "Copy-Item" needs a -Path, which you dont have in your code. I had a similar situation which I solved the following way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -File  -Name | ForEach-Object {Copy-item -Path "C:\Test\$_"  -Destination  "C:\Test\$($_.substring(0,7))"}
```

Therefore, you need to be specific from which path you are copying, however, you can still leave the files being more flexible.

Comment: Thx for your support. Would you please explain the last part?($_.substring(0,7))

Comment: Your very welcome! Sorry for not clarifing it: you can ignore the last part after "-Destination" I just wanted to paste the full code without any gaps, it isnt related to your requirement. However, if you are just interested what it does: "$_" means "each element coming from the pipe" and the "substring(0,7)" cuts the file name from the 1st character to the 7th. I had to copy file 123-123ABC.txt into folder 123-123, therfore the destination folder was just part of the filename itself.